# looping the GRIDVIEW and finding if the Grid has the same Text value in all the rows in one of the column using JQuery on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Let's say there is a grid and on button click I want to check if one of the column "Status" has same value/text in all the rows of the Status column.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPOItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinkButton  ID="btnCancelItem" runat="server">&nbsp;Cancel Item</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am able to loop through the grid but not able to check if the label status has the same `value="Canceled"`.

**JQUERY**

```
function GetCheckedRows() {    
    $("#CP_Main_gvPOItems tr").each(function ()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ok, ihave done it my self here 1st i am **looping the whole grid** then i am using gridcount to count the no.
>   of rows. cancelcount=status having "Cancelled"
>
> **#CP_Main_gvPOItems_lblStatus_**is the **grid client id**
>    **using k as grid client id was coming as CP_Main_gvPOItems_lblStatus_0 (number increasing for col.)**
>   same is the case with grid label status
>   i am directly using the client is that was dynamically coming on the browser as i was unable to find the ID of the label and the grid.

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
             //  alert("hello");
             var gridcount = 0;
             var cancelcount = 0;
             $("#CP_Main_gvPOItems tr").each(function () {
                 //var lbl = $(this).closest('tr').find('td span [id*="CP_Main_gvPOItems_lblStatus_' + k + '"]').text();
                 //var kl = $(this).closest('tr').find('td #lblStatus').html();

                 var status = $("#CP_Main_gvPOItems_lblStatus_" + gridcount).text();

                 if (status.trim() == "Cancelled") {
                     cancelcount++;
                 }
                 gridcount++;

             });

            // alert(gridcount);
            // alert(cancelcount);
             if ((gridcount - 1) == cancelcount) {
                // alert("hello");
                 $("#CP_Main_lblStatus").val("Completed")
                 $('#CP_Main_btnCancelItem').hide();

             } 
        }
```